# Why does the camera wobble at frames 300-303?

Tags: animation, constraints

The attached blend file is a simple animation of the camera following a path while its view is centered on an object. 
If you select the camera and orient your view point on it with NUMPAD-. you can see the camera tilted at frame 301 but at its intended orientation at frame 300 and 302
The path is a Bezier circle that is perpendicular to the Z axis and lies on the XY plane. I have checked all 12 control points to verify this.
The circle is rotated on the Z axis, so that the camera will start at a particular point and the animation parameters are selected so that it will only move along part of the path.

I have looked at the Graph editor zoomed in on frame 301 and can see nothing that would cause this.

Why is this happening.
[image]

Comment: Use a track to constraint instead of damped track https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFwzU.png

Comment: If you hover over Track To, the popup reads, in part, "legacy" and "prone to twisting". I believe Track is deprecated and damped is recommended.

Comment: Verified that this is still happening in 2.79.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a 2.79 bug and the problem has since been fixed.